# Why i'm facing this error (no declaration matches use as "xnor")?

Tags: vhdl

I'm new to VHDL and i'm following a YouTube tutorial to learn VHDL. The instructor wrote this code and it seems to work with him but with me its not working.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity gates is port (
    a : in STD_LOGIC ;
    b : in STD_LOGIC ;
    z : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 downto 0)
    );
end gates;

architecture arch of gates is 
begin
    z(5) <= a and b;
    z(4) <= a nand b;
    z(3) <= a or b;
    z(2) <= a nor b;
    z(1) <= a xor b;
    z(0) <= a xnor b;
end arch;
```

When i try to compile it i get this error message

```
gvhdl: FreeHDL root path is '/usr'.
gvhdl: executing '/usr/bin/freehdl-v2cc -m Desktop/vhdl/new._main_.cc -L /usr/share/freehdl/lib   -o Desktop/vhdl/new.cc Desktop/vhdl/new.vhdl'
Desktop/vhdl/new.vhdl: in gates(imple):
Desktop/vhdl/new.vhdl:18: no declaration matches use as "xnor"(std_logic, std_logic), candidates are
/usr/share/freehdl/lib/std/standard.vhdl:5:  "xnor"(BOOLEAN,BOOLEAN) return BOOLEAN (invalid 0)
/usr/share/freehdl/lib/std/standard.vhdl:6:  "xnor"(BIT,BIT) return BIT (invalid 0)
/usr/share/freehdl/lib/std/standard.vhdl:69:  "xnor"(BIT_VECTOR,BIT_VECTOR) return BIT_VECTOR (invalid 0)
v2cc: Desktop/vhdl/new.vhdl: 1 errors
gvhdl: Compilation failed!
Died at /usr/bin/gvhdl line 211.
```

I'm using freehdl

Comment: The code seems to be perfectly valid, so it must be something related to your simulator. I'd just replace the xnor with a "not (a xor b)" and be done with it.

Comment: @ks0ze i changed `xnor` to `not (a xor b)` and it compiles successfully, but i get linking error. Here is the error message http://pastebin.com/mSa3JsZQ

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with freehdl so hopefully someone else can help you out with that error.

Comment: Prior to [1996](http://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076.2-1996/) the std_logic_1164 package source did not have "xnor" uncommented. Noting your pastebin error messages don't appear to match the above source or there is something environmental going on. Without recent experience building FreeHDL or gvhdl you're on your own. Consider [ghdl](https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl/releases). The mcode version has no dependencies and is compact, the llvm version doesn't depend on gcc and they're both easy to [build](https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl/blob/master/BUILD.txt) yourself.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code - [gates_tb.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFsGw.png). This was done with ghdl which has a batch simulator requiring a [testbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAKC4.jpg)..

Comment: Try compiling for a newer VHDL standard to get the packages with xnor ... does your compiler support VHDL-2008? If not, I second the ghdl suggestion.

Comment: @user8352 how did you compiled the code ? i used this command `gvhdl code.vhdl` and its not working

Comment: @BrianDrummond what is VHDL-2008? how to know whether my compiler supports it or not? i used this command to compile my code `gvhdl code.vhdl` and i got this error http://pastebin.com/mSa3JsZQ

Comment: Check your documentation for supported VHDL language revisions. With ghdl, you select VHDL with `ghdl -a --std=08 gates.vhd`

Comment: The linking issues in the comments with the pastebin web link appear related to related to finding VHDL library names (see the man page for gvhdl).  Those missing symbols are all declared in std_logic_1164.cc. Why that wasn't a problem previously is not apparent unless you have changed something in your execution environment or the FreeHDL installation. Without building or having FreeHDL installed interpreting linking problems doesn't seem possible. There's no apparent source for FreeHDL support.

Answer (score 1):

Change the xor line to not (a xor b):

> z(0) <= not (a xor b);

and then compile with the

> --libieee

option. This is important. Otherwise you'll receive linker errors.

> gvhdl --libieee myFile.vhdl